# JavaScript on Appcelerator. Extract data from callback function

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing a Titanium Appcelerator app.

I got a function in a separate file that returns a section for a table view (http://pastie.org/1734554) and on the main file I got a call to this function with a callback. I want to be able to extract the callback data and add it to an array (http://pastie.org/1734548) but I cannot get that data out of the calling function. How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You’re running into the asynchronous nature of AJAX.  Move your alert to within the callback function, and it’ll work as expected:

```
var rowData = [];

rowData.push("THIS ADDS TO THE ARRAY");

loadPhones(function(data) { 
    rowData.push(data);
    alert(rowData);
});
```

The reason you have to pass a function to `loadPhones` is that you don’t want the browser to lock up while you’re retrieving the list of phones.  The way you had written it, the anonymous callback function had not been executed by the time you got to the `alert` statement.

Do whatever you need to do with the retrieved data inside the loadPhones callback.

Comment: Ah ok, yes I can do the alert inside the function as you did but I need to push the data into the rowData array so that I can use it otherwise the function is useless. Isn´t there a way to do this?

Comment: @JonathanClark: Of course, that already happens.  Your problem is related to _when_ the array is accessed.  If you put that code right after `loadPhones`, it won't be accessible yet, because the callback won't have been executed.  When do you need to access the data, and what for?